# Performance issues with KonvaJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs, konvajs

I have a project that uses KonvaJS (I recently ported it from KineticJS) in a peculiar way. I basically use it to show 3D representations of buildings in a isometric view as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfED6.png).

Initially everything worked fine, but with the icreasing of building size the performance started to take a hit, because I have to represent the lighting of the building, and each luminaire has 3 polygons. I use only a layer and groups, the stage is draggable and every luminaire is selectable, so I use mouse events.

The main problems that I'm facing is the redrawing the stage when dragging and also when pointing and zooming. For example, I have a big building with almost 2000 luminaires and it's impossible to work with it.

Here's a simplified version of my node list.

- Stage

  - Layer

    - wallsISO (group)

      - n x polygon
    - floorISO (group)

      - n x polygon
    - luminairesISO (group)

      - singleLuminaire (group)

        - 3 x polygon
      - singleLuminaire (group)
      - ...

Should I use different layers? Will it be better? Is there anything that I'm missing? I'm starting to think I should've used a 3D framework.

Comment: *Good news / Bad news:* KonvaJS is a great framework for creating interactive polygons on a canvas, but 2000 "smart" polygons is too many. Instead, draw your polygons on native html5 canvas and use mathematical hit-testing to do your dragging and selecting. The dragging & selecting process should be very responsive since the bulk of your luminaires are inside a few hierarchical groups.

Comment: Did you try all tips from here: http://konvajs.github.io/docs/performance/All_Performance_Tips.html ?
Caching is one of the best way.

Comment: I've tried everything. for example, the caching takes too much time to convert to image and  then revert.